# How can I use the Mac iOS Simulator together with Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I want to use the iOS Simulator from a Mac and run the Emulator as stated here: http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/debug/

> iOS Simulator
>   The Mac PC which is hosting the iOS Simulator and the Windows PC which is running the Smartface App Studio can communicate directly over TCP/IP.

This is not working.

Can anyone explain me step by step how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

iOS Emulator of Smartface App Studio requires directly USB connection to your Windows PC with your iOS Device in order to make emulation and debug.

You should use real iOS device which is connected to Windows Machine.

For more information :

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/tips/ios-emulator-troubleshooting/

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/debug/

http://www.smartface.io/ios-and-android-emulator-on-windows/